# Get allocated memory regions of running process

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, process

Can anyone tell me how to get using WinAPI functions memory allocated memory regions of some process? I want know for each region, start address, size and some other things like, protect type etc.

I can't find any WinAPI function to do it ;-(

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is code to brute force this using `VirtualQueryEx` [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/MDumpAll.aspx):

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION    mbi;
/* Get maximum address range from system info */
GetSystemInfo(&si);
/* walk process addresses */
lpMem = 0;
while (lpMem < si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress) {
        VirtualQueryEx(...)
        /* increment lpMem to next region of memory */
        lpMem = (LPVOID)((DWORD)lpList->mbi.BaseAddress +
        (DWORD)lpList->mbi.RegionSize);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use `GetSystemInfo`. Alternatively you may continue the loop until `VirtualQueryEx` "fails".

Comment: I am just curious. Memory of one process is not contiguous. if `VirtualQueryEx()` fails and u stop the loop will it find all the memory or just stop at 1st occurrence of allocated memory for the process?