# Execute remote function with memory address as parameter

Tags: windows, memory, ollydbg, createremotethread

I'm trying to execute a function in a running (old) Win32 Borland application (Window has class OLW_WINDOW). By using OllyDbg I've found out that the function has one parameter which is a memory address. One variable/value used by the function is stored at an offset of that address. My idea is to find that memory address (which is at an constant offset in a memory block), change the variable/value to what I want and then execute the function. To use WriteProcessMemory and CreateRemoteThread to execute is okey, but the problem is how to find the memory address/block? When opening "Memory map" in OllyDbg the memory block has no owner, section or contains. Is it possible to get a list of memory blocks created by a specified thread? Or could I get it from the application somehow? Btw: the function is normally executed when a button is clicked and the variable/value I want to set is a database ID listed (by name) in a listview (or equivalent).

Comment: If the memory address is a parameter of the function, can't you provide any address you like?

Comment: I could, but I'm afaird the memory address also contains other variables the function use like database connection handle. But I found a (partial) answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035313/get-allocated-memory-regions-of-running-process)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is just call the function.

As an example here is a function which prints output to a console:

```cpp
void ConsoleOutput(char* text);
```

To call it, we would find the address of this function in the target binary.  Let's say it's found at 0xDEADC0DE.

We would form a typedef for a function pointer:

```
typedef void(__cdecl* tConsoleOutput)(char* text);
```

We would create an instance of that function pointer type

```
tConsoleOutput ConsoleOutput = (ConsoleOutput)0xDEADC0DE;
```

To call the function we would simply do:

```
ConsoleOutput("Hello");
```

Likewise for your project, you would input whatever argument you required.